# Is it possible to trigger `OnMouseEnter` event with one line of code for multiple divs using Jquery, Javascript,

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have following code which i echo (print) via `PHP` on every video for thumbnail preview. All div `ids` are numeric like `id="1246575"`. Is there a `foreach` like possibility to achieve this for example, for every numeric div do this function in javascript or jquery?

```
$(function(){
  $("#'.$id.'").mouseenter(function(){
    fadeimg("'.$json.'","'.$id.'","'.$site.'");                             
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use the PHP to add the needed stuff as data attribute to the tag
   `... "<sometag data-targetID='".$id."' class="fadeable" />";` and give the tags a class
2. use the jQuery (delegated if needed)
   `$(".fadeable").mouseenter(function(){ var id = $(this).data("targetID"); fadeImg(id);`

Comment: This could work except i need to output 3 variables for my preview to work, i need the id, i need the thumbs directory and i need the name of the site from which the videos where stored for some if conditions while output json array.

Comment: Sorry your answer is the solution i just realised i can output all variables in the html class and then assign them through $(this).data("target-"). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `$json`, `$id` and `$site` variables as `data-*` attributes and retrieve it's values on mouseenter and pass to a function like this:

```
echo "<div id='123' data-json='$json' data-id='$id' data-site='$site'></div>"
```

And then:

```
$('div[id]').filter(function(){ 

    return (this.id && this.id.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) 

}).on('mouseenter', function(){ 

    var data = $(this).data();

    fadeimg(data.json, data.id, data.site); 

})
```